# .NET: Is there a Class to copy properties of one class to another

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I wrote a function that copies the properties of one class to another so make a copy of an object.

So something like

```
MyObject myObject = myOtherObject.MyCustomCopy(myObject)
```

where myObject and myOtherObject are of the same type. I do it by bascually doing

```
myObject.prop1 = myOtherObject.prop1
myObject.prop2 = myOtherObject.prop2
myObject.prop3 = myOtherObject.prop3
return myObject
```

I am pretty sure in the past I used a .NET object that automaticaly did this, by reflection I guess, but can't remember it ... or an I imagining that such a method exists?

Yes I'm aware of auto mapper but i was sure (not so much now) that there is a .NET object that does the job. Maybe not!

Answer (score 12):

You may take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Had to check the timestamps for this one :)

Answer (score 10):

```
 public static class ext
{
    public static void CopyAllTo<T>(this T source, T target)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        foreach (var sourceProperty in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var targetProperty = type.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
            targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
        foreach (var sourceField in type.GetFields())
        {
            var targetField = type.GetField(sourceField.Name);
            targetField.SetValue(target, sourceField.GetValue(source));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AutoMapper mentioned above is much more powerful, but for simple use cases like mine, this is much simpler and faster to get running with. Thanks!

Comment: Automapper will give you a new reference object with the copied properties,whereas this solution will copy properties between existing references which is what the question needs

Answer (score 6):

You should use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) it was built for this job.

Comment: The question is how to make a copy of an object, not how to copy the property values of an object to a different type object.

Comment: You can clone objects this way too.

Answer (score 2):

[System.Object.MemberwiseClone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)

Comment: Hi bitbonk, that actually does not copy reference types, it just copies the reference

Answer (score 1):

Try description in this link:

[.NET Reflection - Copy Class Properties](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a4264125-fcb0-4757-9d78-ff541dfbcb56/net-reflection--copy-cl.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for basic property types, not sure how it'll go for anything complex (lists, arrays, custom classes).  Should be a starting point though:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int A { get; set; }
  public string B { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyClass orig = new MyClass() { A = 1, B = "hello" };
  MyClass copy = new MyClass();

  PropertyInfo[] infos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
  foreach (PropertyInfo info in infos)
  {
    info.SetValue(copy, info.GetValue(orig, null), null);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(copy.A + ", " + copy.B);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP did not ask for a Type to another Type but my variant is one I use for DI in startup.cs for mismatches in configurations between cloud and local dev environment. My local class generally uses a Interface class behind the scenes to map the configurations. Then I use this method to copy properties where they match in name only. I am not checking property types since these are configurations. AutoMapper was suggested. I don't use AutoMapper because we are restricted by U.S. DOD to certain providers. Getting an ATO is hard enough just using .NET, we don't need any more grief.

```
  using System.Linq;
  public static class PropertyCopy
  {
    public static void CopyAllTo<T,T1>(this T source, T1 target)
    {
      var type = typeof(T);
      var type1 = typeof(T1);
      foreach (var sourceProperty in type.GetProperties())
      {
        foreach (var targetProperty in type1.GetProperties()
          .Where(targetProperty => sourceProperty.Name == targetProperty.Name)
          .Where(targetProperty => targetProperty.SetMethod != null))
        {
          targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
      }

      foreach (var sourceField in type.GetFields())
      {
        foreach (var targetField in type1.GetFields()
          .Where(targetField => sourceField.Name == targetField.Name))
        {
          targetField.SetValue(target, sourceField.GetValue(source));
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms: As we know Classes are reference types in C#.NET i.e. when we create a object of a class such as

```
Customer C1=new Customer();
C1.Id=1;
C1.Name="Rakesh";
```

Then C1(Reference variable) is stored on memory stack and object new Customer() is stored on Heap.

Hence when we copy a class into another class which is basically your question you can do something like below:

```
Customer C2=C1;
```

Doing above will copy the C1 Reference variable into C2 But why I wrote about Stack and Heap because using C2 reference variable you can change the object properties being both C1 and C2 pointing to same object in HEAP.Something Like

```
C2.Id=1;
C2.Name="Mukesh";
```

Now if you will try to access `C1.Name` you will see it is changed to "Mukesh".

Answer (score 0):

you can use JsonConvert like this:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject);
MyClass object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);
```